# How to properly generate security header for SOAP request in C#?

Tags: c#, soap, ws-security

I'm trying to consume a SOAP service using C#, but I'm struggling with Outgoing WS-Security configuration.

What I've done so far:

1. Created a service reference in VS 2019 and extended the generated Client class to pass my configuration in there
2. Created a custom endpoint behavior:

```
    this.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new WsSecurityEndpointBehavior(username, password, timeout));
    // ...

    public class WsSecurityEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        private readonly string _password;
        private readonly TimeSpan _timeout;
        private readonly string _username;
    
        public WsSecurityEndpointBehavior(string username, string password, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            this._username = username;
            this._password = password;
            this._timeout = timeout;
        }
    
        void IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint,
            BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }
    
        void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new WsSecurityMessageInspector(_username, _password, _timeout));
        }
        void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
        }
    
        void IEndpointBehavior.Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }
    }
```

3. Created a ClientMessageInspector:

```
    public class WsSecurityMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        private readonly string _password;
        private readonly TimeSpan _timeout;
        private readonly string _username;
    
        public WsSecurityMessageInspector(string username, string password, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            this._username = username;
            this._password = password;
            this._timeout = timeout;
        }
    
        object IClientMessageInspector.BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            var header = new Security
            {
                UsernameToken =
                {
                    Password = new Password
                    {
                        Value = _password,
                        Type =
                            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest"
                    },
                    Username = _username
                },
                Timestamp =
                {
                    Created = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ"),
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(_timeout).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ")
                }
            };
            request.Headers.Add(header);
            return null;
        }
    
        void IClientMessageInspector.AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
        }

}
```

4. Added poco classes for xml fields:

```
    public class Password
    {
        [XmlAttribute] public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlText] public string Value { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class UsernameToken
    {
        [XmlElement] public string Username { get; set; }
        [XmlElement] public Password Password { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Timestamp
    {
        [XmlElement] public string Created { get; set; }
        [XmlElement] public string Expires { get; set; }
    }
```

5. And finally implemented a Security message header:

```
    public class Security : MessageHeader
    {
        public Security()
        {
            UsernameToken = new UsernameToken();
            Timestamp = new Timestamp();
        }
    
        public UsernameToken UsernameToken { get; set; }
        public Timestamp Timestamp { get; set; }
    
        public const string SoapEnvelopeNamespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
        public const string WsseUtilityNamespaceUrl = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd";
        public const string WsseNamespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";
    
    
        public override string Name => GetType().Name;
    
        public override string Namespace => WsseNamespace;
    
        public override bool MustUnderstand => true;
    
        protected override void OnWriteStartHeader(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", Name, Namespace);
            //writer.WriteAttributeString("s", "mustUnderstand", SoapEnvelopeNamespace, "1"); // - doesn't work either way
    
            writer.WriteXmlnsAttribute("wsse", Namespace);
            writer.WriteXmlnsAttribute("wsu", WsseUtilityNamespaceUrl);
        }
    
        protected override void OnWriteHeaderContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, MessageVersion messageVersion)
        {
            // Timestamp
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsu", "Timestamp", WsseUtilityNamespaceUrl);
    
            writer.WriteAttributeString("wsu", "Id", WsseUtilityNamespaceUrl, "TS-" + Guid.NewGuid());
    
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsu", "Created", WsseUtilityNamespaceUrl);
            writer.WriteValue(Timestamp.Created);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
    
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsu", "Expires", WsseUtilityNamespaceUrl);
            writer.WriteValue(Timestamp.Expires);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
    
            writer.WriteEndElement(); // Timestamp
    
            // username token
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "UsernameToken", Namespace);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("wsu", "Id", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken-" + Guid.NewGuid());
            // Username
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Username", Namespace);
            writer.WriteValue(UsernameToken.Username);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
    
            var nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            var createdStr = Timestamp.Created;
            var pwd = GetSHA1String(nonce + createdStr + UsernameToken.Password.Value);
    
            // Password
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Password", Namespace);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("Type", UsernameToken.Password.Type); //PasswordDigest
            writer.WriteValue(pwd);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
    
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsse", "Nonce", Namespace);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("EncodingType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");
            writer.WriteValue(nonce);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
    
            writer.WriteStartElement("wsu", "Created", WsseUtilityNamespaceUrl);
            writer.WriteValue(createdStr);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
    
            // username token
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    
        private static string GetSHA1String(string phrase)
        {
            var sha1Hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            var hashedDataBytes = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(phrase));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedDataBytes);
        }
    }
```

And the XML example I have in the result:

```
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
        xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-2b7092f4-8f62-40b5-8f7e-ab774ef967aa">
            <wsu:Created>2021-05-17T10:20:16.913Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2021-05-17T10:25:16.913Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-8ee97b0e-cbdf-465b-97b0-8e5194f2f4a9">
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">base64_described_above</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">MGNiNDUxMTYtYjBlMy00ZmQzLTgwYTUtODgxZGY2NmUyMDI0</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2021-05-17T10:20:16.913Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
```

I was able to make it work in Soap UI, but with this C# implementation I'm getting `ns1:SecurityError`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---- **UPDATE** ----
The full request XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Header>
            <Action s:mustUnderstand="1"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">[ActionICall]</Action>
            <h:RequestContext xmlns="http://hidden-for-security/webservices/v1/messages"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:h="http://hidden-for-security/webservices/v1/messages">
                <Id>f7ed31dc-b7ad-4a5d-ae17-c86663bbb2da</Id>
                <Language>en</Language>
            </h:RequestContext>
            <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-ceb077e4-3255-405b-aac7-d7ae9bf1b884">
                    <wsu:Created>2021-05-17T12:01:11.852Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>2021-05-17T12:06:11.852Z</wsu:Expires>
                </wsu:Timestamp>
                <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1373fa47-6f2a-4d44-87d5-5270132f9830">
                    <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">calculated-password-in-base64</wsse:Password>
                    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">MjkxY2VkY2MtZjA4ZC00NmQ0LWFkMjUtYWQ4ZGU3ODFmNGVm</wsse:Nonce>
                    <wsu:Created>2021-05-17T12:01:11.852Z</wsu:Created>
                </wsse:UsernameToken>
            </wsse:Security>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <ActionICallRequest xmlns="http://hidden-for-security/webservices/v1/messages">
                <UniqueNumber xmlns="http://hidden-for-security/webservices/v1/datamodel">659648795</UniqueNumber>
            </ActionICallRequest>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

The response I get:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
      <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
          <faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://ws.apache.org/wss4j">ns1:SecurityError</faultcode>
          <faultstring>A security error was encountered when verifying the message</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: You are getting "ns1" which is a namespace error.  Is the XML shown above the the output of the c# code?

Comment: yes, this is C# output

Comment: Expiration date is same as creation date. Is that correct?  You only have a header posted the ns1 is probably in the body and the url for the namespace may be missing.

Comment: expiration date is creation date + timestamp (5 minutes in my case). I updated the question with full request and response XMLs

Comment: There are two common type issue with code like this 1) Base64 encoding.  Looks like you need to run Convert.ToBase64String(string) 2) The padding mode is wrong for encryption. JSON and c# have different default padding mode.  I also notice the body of the request is using the default namespace which may be why you are getting "ns1".  I would make sure the body has the correct namespace. The error says "verifying message", not a encrypt/decrypt error. So I think the error is the structure of the request and not the data inside.

Comment: even if I take the XML which I successfully sent using Soap UI (by copying it from logs) and replace password, nonce, created and expires fields (leaving the rest exactly the same), it returns the same error.  Could you elaborate on what do you mean be padding mode?

Comment: See Key Info : https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSOAPSEC_BODYENCR&force_isolation=true

Comment: Is your encoding suppose to be UTF-8 or UTF-16?  What sample are you using to compare the SOAP Format?

Comment: In the example they're using UTF-8: ```<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-8”?>
```, but my C# code generates utf-16 for some reason. And I'm not quite sure how to change it to UTF-8 which is supposed to be the default encoding. I tried to ```httpsBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8```, but the result is the same. Moreover if I put there Encoding.Unicode, I'm getting an error: "An XML declaration is required for all non-UTF8 documents".

Comment: I usually just parse a string for the first lines which can contain complicated namespaces that are hard to handle in Net. Try :            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                               "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                               "</s:Envelope>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement envelope = doc.Root;